# How to block the click event to the background of DialogFragment around Samsung S9 Edge button

Tags: android

I have a UI requirement showing a blocking DialogFragment, which can not be dismissed by clicking on the background.
Also when the DialogFragment is showing, any view under it cannot be clicked.

> **Things are working well except on the Samsung S9 device.**

On Samsung S9, which has an edge button, when clicking around the edge button's edge, the view under the DialogFragment got clicked and the event performed, which is not as expected.

Here is a sample code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
            myDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), MyDialogFragment.TAG);

        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.background).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("wrong", "clicked!!!!---------------");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Click!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

The layout is quite simple, just a LinearLayout with a button inside it.
Clicking button will show the blocking dialog.
The LinearLayout id is background, which should not be clicked after the dialog has shown.

The dialog code:

public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public static final String TAG = "Dialog";

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setCancelable(false);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_layout, container, false);
    getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    Point size = new Point();
    Display display = window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(size);
    window.setLayout((int) (size.x * 0.8), WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

**But now when the dialog is showing, click the area on the edge button, the background click listener can be entered, I can get the log and toast.**

**How to prevent this?**

Answer (score 1):

In the event that is firing I'd do

```
Fragment currentFrag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MyDialogFragment_TAG);
if (!(currentFrag instanceof MyDialogFragment))
{
  // your code for when you're dialog fragment is not visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setcancelable(false); can be used to block clicking on background till task completes

Comment: I already set that one(see code in onCreate).  It works on other devices but can not block the touch area around samsung s9 edge button.

Answer (score 0):

Give the root node an id

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/constraintlayoutRoot"
```

Add an empty OnClickListener

```
    public View onCreateView(...) {
    View view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_xyz, _container, false);
    view.findViewById(R.id.constraintlayoutRoot).setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
    });
```